# What happens when I do an iTunes Connect phased release?

Tags: app-store-connect, release, automatic-updates

iTunes Connect now lets me release an app with a phased release. Here's the web UI that explains this.

[image: Phased release option]

What actually happens once the update is released to users? What control and feedback do I get?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apple have summarised the process in the help text pretty well. It brings up most of the salient points.

Here's the UI that you get in iTunesConnect during a phased release.

[image: Phase release interaction]

Here's a summary of a few things – several obvious, some less so:

- New users get the update, not the old version.
- Users can download the update manually if they wish – it is only automatic updates that are phased.
- You can pause the roll out (for up to 30 days). – I presume you can do this multiple times.
- There is a button (at the top right App's page) that allows you to **"Release to all users"** immediately.

The progress of the phased release **is not linear**. It is very gradual initially, then ramps up at the end. This means you test the water on day one with 1% of users. The roll out is shaped like this:

- Day 1 – 1% get the update – 1% are on update.
- Day 2 – 1% more get the update – 2% are on update.
- Day 3 – 3% more get the update – 5% are on update.
- Day 4 – 5% more get the update – 10% are on update.
- Day 5 – 10% more get the update – 20% are on update.
- Day 6 – 30% more get the update – 50% are on update.
- Day 7 – 50% more get update – 100% are on update.

## Pausing Releases

If you choose to pause a release, then the interface will give you some further information about this state.

[image: Pausing release]

In particular, note that users **can still update to this version manually** if they chose to. So, pausing the phased release doesn't let you completely stop updates if you find a critical issue with your release. However it should be pretty effective as most users probably don't check for updates manually.

## Providing An Update

During a phased release, you can create a new update. You can create the update if the phased release is paused.

So, if we create an update **B** that we see early on in the phased release has critical issues, then we can pause that phased release and create a new update **F** to fix the problems.

Until **F** is available, users can manually update to **B** if they choose to, but most probably won't manually update.

## Unanswered Questions

A few remaining points I'll add answers for if I become aware of them.

**Is the phasing order by users or by devices**? The text mentions "users", but it's not very explicit. If the ordering is by device, a user might have their phone update on day 1, their iPad day 3, their watch day 6, and Apple TV day 7.

**Are future rollouts ordered the same way**? Or is a fresh ordering picked so that different users go first and last? Or is the order not explicit and just random? In particular, this has implications for a bad release that you are patching with a fix. You might just release the fix if you're sure it doesn't have any problems of its own. But if you phase the fix, half of the users that got the bad release could be stuck with it for a week.

Comment: I can't see the merit of this answer if it just summarizes the obvious and concludes with new questions. If you put everything in your question, it would be a well researched and focused one (even with 2 questions).

Comment: @Filburt Updating comment – I got answers to some of the questions I posed. I've still got some outstanding ones. I felt it was important to show the UI of what happens during a phased release (and pausing). I agree this could have been just a question – I may restructure. However, the _title_ would be very specific stuff. People searching might not realise that the page has information applicable to them.

Comment: @Benjohn Were you able to find the answers for the questions posed? If you have, it would be helpful if you could share.

Comment: Hi @user3400887 – no, I don't have answers for this, sorry. I've also had a quick google and not found an answer to the critical fix issue that I mention.

Comment: @Benjohn If i upload a new build during the phased rollout period, does the 7-day or 30-day pause clock reset?  Are we allowed to revert to an older build in case the newer build is a total crapshoot and we have to take it out of the app store?

Comment: Hi @AndroidNoob 1) Uploading a new build does not interact with phased roll out, regardless of whether the roll out is paused or not (as far as I know – I'm happy to stand corrected though!). 2) I don't believe there is a way to revert to an old build with or without a phased rollout (I'm very confident about this assertion, but again – happy to stand corrected!).

Comment: @Benjohn during the staged rollout, when does the clock start/stop?  Does each day start at 12:00 AM or is does it count 24 hours from when you press the "Start" button.

Comment: @AndroidNoob I believe the clock starts at the time the App is released. However, this is not something I am certain of. You can schedule a release date & time yourself, or make the release manually, or allow the App to release as soon as Apple have completed their review.

Comment: @BenJohn My colleague and I contacted Apple Support and the reply we got was what you mentioned.  So if I submit the app for review on 8PM on Monday, the clock starts.  The next "day" in that case would start on 8PM on Tuesday.

Comment: Hi @AndroidNoob thanks for checking and for adding the comment! … A clarification though, do you mean "if I submit the app for review"? Because reviews can pend after submission for several days, and apps are sometimes "in review" also for considerable time. I think you meant "once an app is release", or some such?

Comment: It is worth noting that you CAN prevent users from grabbing the latest "broken" version of your app by removing the version from the "pricing and availability" section of the app store connect BUT ONLY IF you have uploaded a newer version and created the version, (preparing for submission) even if that new version's .ipa is still processing

Comment: What happens after 30 days of pausing?

Comment: Did Apple ever mention that they will add country specific phased rollouts like on the play store?

Comment: @TimChristmann Hi – I don't know, sorry, but that sounds like a nice feature. Perhaps someone else will comment, or it would make a good new question.